# how to resolve NoSuchFieldError in jive through Maven Shade Plugin Relocation

Tags: maven, jar, rename, conflict, maven-shade-plugin

Somewhere in the code from jive 6 uses `httpcore-4.0.1.jar`.

However, in my plugin, `httpcore-4.3.2.jar` is used.

Due to this jar conflict, I saw `NoSuchFieldError` when running jive's cargo-start.

After investigating, I found a nice link about Maven Shade Plugin solution at http://thinkoutofthenet.com (see 2nd topic at the link above).

I was expecting that Maven Shade Plugin can rename

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
```

to

```
import embedded.org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
```

through the following change in `pom.xml`. However, it didn't work. Does anyone know what goes wrong ? and how I can resolve the current issue I have ?

```
...
<build>
  <finalName>${final.name}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.apache.http.impl</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>embedded.org.apache.http.impl</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue right now.